# How to vertically align text within <div> element css?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension for the first time and am trying to centre text. And the moment I am using `text-align: centre;` to horizontally align it but can't figure out how to vertically align so at the moment my text looks like this:

[image: screenshot of extension]

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ex) display: table

```css
div{
  display: table;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

div p{
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>chatter</p>
</div>
```

ex) flex

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

div p{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>chatter</p>
</div>
```

ex) position

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
div p{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>chatter</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well for me! good solution.

Answer (score 1):

A really simple class I use for this is

```
.is-vertical-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this helps!